# How to display the querydict using loop

Tags: python, django

I am creating a function that will display the values and the key of querydict. for example if I got a QueryDict on a GET Request.

```
<QueryDict: {u'val1':[u'aa'],u'val2':[u'ab'],u'val3':[u'ac'],u'val4':[u'ad'], ... u'valn':[u'an'] ...}>
```

my function is now just like this:

```
def displayQueryDicts(self, request):
    for x in request:
     print x # this will return the val1, val2, val3, val4, ..., valn
     print x .value() # I don't know how to print all the values
```

My question now is, how can I print the values just like this..

```
val1   aa
val2   ab
val3   ac
val4   ad
...    ...
valn   an
```

Comment: Did the answer help to solve the problem, is there anything to improve? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET):

> `HttpRequest.GET`
>
> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP GET parameters.

You can iterate over it like over a normal python `dict`:

```
for key, value in request.GET.items():
    print "%s %s" % (key, value)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

In python3 you would do

```
 for key, value in request.GET.items():
        print ("%s %s" % (key, value))
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that a `QueryDict` is only a dictionary-like object.  There is an important distinction.  From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects):

> In an HttpRequest object, the GET and POST attributes are instances of django.http.QueryDict, a dictionary-like class customized to deal with multiple values for the same key. This is necessary because some HTML form elements, notably , pass multiple values for the same key.

If you want to iterate over all arguments of the request and have multiple with the same key, you need to use `QueryDict.lists()` in Python 3 or `QueryDict.iterlists()` in Python 2.  See the documentation for the [output format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists).

Answer (score 2):

**for Python 3.x:**

You can use [**`QueryDict.lists()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists) method of QueryDict.
It includes all values, as a list, for each *member/key* of the dictionary.

```
for key, value in QueryDict(query_string).lists():
    ...
```

OR

```
for key, value in request.GET.lists():
    ...
```

OR

```
for key, value in request.POST.lists():
    ...
```

***Note:*** This is different from [**`QueryDict.items()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.items) which returns the last value of the given *member/key* if there are more than one value present for that *member/key*.